# Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error - confused?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, linker-errors, mach-o

My project had no errors until I did a build. Here's the error log.

```
Ld "/Users/stephanieasan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WC_Class_Codes-fgxjeudpfimhnebtmvmxtzlirxnz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WC Class Codes.app/WC Class Codes" normal i386
cd "/Users/stephanieasan/Desktop/SDK Projects/WC Class Codes"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/stephanieasan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WC_Class_Codes-fgxjeudpfimhnebtmvmxtzlirxnz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/stephanieasan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WC_Class_Codes-fgxjeudpfimhnebtmvmxtzlirxnz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/stephanieasan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WC_Class_Codes-fgxjeudpfimhnebtmvmxtzlirxnz/Build/Intermediates/WC Class Codes.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WC Class Codes.build/Objects-normal/i386/WC Class Codes.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -framework iAd -lsqlite3.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Users/stephanieasan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WC_Class_Codes-fgxjeudpfimhnebtmvmxtzlirxnz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WC Class Codes.app/WC Class Codes"
```

.

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ListTableViewController.DBPath in /Users/stephanieasan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WC_Class_Codes-fgxjeudpfimhnebtmvmxtzlirxnz/Build/Intermediates/WC Class Codes.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WC Class Codes.build/Objects-normal/i386/Code.o and /Users/stephanieasan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WC_Class_Codes-fgxjeudpfimhnebtmvmxtzlirxnz/Build/Intermediates/WC Class Codes.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WC Class Codes.build/Objects-normal/i386/ListTableViewController.o for architecture i386
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I am very confused, I have been trying to debug this for hours with no success.

Comment: The only thing I can gather from this is that you have a duplicate definition of `ListTableViewController` in your project. It's difficult to say exactly why without more details about your project. A minimal example that produces the same error would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have a global variable called DBPath, perhaps defined in the class called "Code" as well as in the class called "ListTableViewController"? Each class is likely compilable by itself, but when you try to link them into the same executable you are getting a conflict.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `Code.m`, you accidentally said this:

```
#import "ListTableViewController.m"
```

You meant to say this:

```
#import "ListTableViewController.h"
```

Comment: You've saved me twice in 20 min! This was bugging me for a long time!

Comment: Keep asking easy ones and I'll keep saving you. ;)

Comment: for search .m file in entire project just search with .m" and change that file with .h

Answer (score -1):

Or the class that you're trying to import has similar class name.

Comment: Please provide more information on your assumption.

Comment: I encountered this error a while a go and searched for a solution 'til I see this post but I see that I import the right class. Then I noticed that the newly created class that I'm trying to import is already created by my colleague under some folder. When I deleted the one I made, error is gone.